# How can I cross-list an article on the arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

I know how to cross-list between sub-disciplines, for example hep-th and cond-mat under the physics discipline. I am having trouble cross-listing between higher-level disciplines, for example physics and computer science. Could the problem be that I am only endorsed for one of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`My account` -> `Change user information` -> `Group(s) you would like to submit to` and you check the relevant categories. A hint might be (from the [help](https://arxiv.org/help/cross)): "*Also note that you are unlikely to know that a cross-list is appropriate unless you are yourself a reader of the archive to which you are considering a cross-list*". I had to write an e-mail to arXiv some time ago to learn how to cross-list.